# Can an immigrant with an electronic tag (ankle monitor) be hired?

Tags: employment, immigration

My parents own a small restaurant.
While they were looking for a full-time employee, Latino woman, a mother of one child, applied with all the qualifying documents like SSN, and etc. (according to my parents and their CPA).

The thing is she is wearing an electronic tag around her ankle. She explained that it was due to her status in US.

Is it okay to hire a person in her situation?

If so, how long can she stay in US?

Answer (score 2):

The CPA should be doing an I-9 Form with the USCIS on the potential employee, as filing such a form is required by law; you can't clearly know her legal employment status in the US unless one has been completed: https://www.uscis.gov/i-9

> Form I-9 is used for verifying the identity and employment
>   authorization of individuals hired for employment in the United
>   States. All U.S. employers must ensure proper completion of Form I-9
>   for each individual they hire for employment in the United States.
>   This includes citizens and noncitizens.

The state you are in may also have employment laws that pertain to people who are required to file an I-9; check with the state government.

The ankle bracelet doesn't have anything to do with the I-9 Form; but it may mean she was simply in INS detention. Or she is possibly dealing with other law enforcement agencies on non-immigration issues.

Comment: GPS tags are used on some sex offenders on probation, so it might be worth checking the sex offender registry.